# Display table in angular with complex JSON data

Tags: json, angular, angular-material

I need to display the below JSON data as in the table format. The data is coming from service. I want to display like the excel sheet image ( which i uploaded) . I tried a lot, but i could not complete. someone please help me

JSON Data

```
{ 
   "itemName":"ABC",
   "head1":"238364",
   "head2":null,
   "head3":"9",
   "head4":"Level 3",
   "dataList":[ 
      {
         "QName":"Phase 1 - Dummy1",
         "subDataList":[ 
            {
               "subDataName":null,
               "taskList":[ 
                  { 
                     "name":"junk1",
                     "iheader1":10,
                     "iheader2":10000.0,
                     "iheader3":3.5,
                     "iheader4":3500.0
                   },
                  { 
                     "name":"junk2",
                     "iheader1":10,
                     "iheader2":10000.0,
                     "iheader3":3.5,
                     "iheader4":3500.0
                   } 
                ]
             }
          ]
       },
      {
         "QName":"Phase  3 - Dummy3",

         "subDataList":[ 
            {
               "subDataName":additionalHead1,
               "taskList":[ 
                  { 
                      "name":"junk1",
                     "iheader1":10,
                     "iheader2":10000.0,
                     "iheader3":3.5,
                     "iheader4":3500.0
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }

    ],

      "TOTAL1":{ 
         "taskName":"[A] Total XXXX",
          "iheader1":10,
           "iheader2":10000.0,
           "iheader3":3.5,
           "iheader4":3500.0
       },
      "TOTAL2":{ 
         "taskName":"[B] Total XXXXX",
          "iheader1":10,
           "iheader2":10000.0,
           "iheader3":3.5,
           "iheader4":3500.0
       }


    }
}
```

it should be display like the image
[image]

Thanks in advance
Manivannan

Comment: what is the issue you are facing

Comment: Thanks for your response my friend..  Not sure how to display it in table format. If tried to use material table, and if i give the datasource as the json file it is not working. Also i am not sure how to segregate column names  as mentioned in the image since only items of task list has data for all four column and other does not. Not sure how to iterate sublists inside material table. As i am new to angular

Comment: this is one basic example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-json-data-to-a-html-table-using-javascript-jquery/

Comment: Thank you so much @shloknangia . I created my table as described in the link. It worked as expected. Thanks